# Interpretation of residuals in glm, with gamma distribution

Tags: generalized-linear-model, residuals, gamma-distribution

I am using glm in R to fit model to my data (gene expression in different samples ~ var1+var2+var3...). My aim is to calculate residuals (for each sample), look at distribution (histogram) and find the samples which have higher unexplained variance (represented by higher residual score).

When using the gaussian distribution, the residuals are normally distributed with mean close to zero, so in this case I pick up bottom/top 5% samples which have higher residual score.

But in case of gamma distribution, the distribution of residual score is not normal (mean is non-zero). In this case how should I interpret the residuals and categorize samples which have higher unexplained variance?

Comment: Why not just take the top 10% of cases by residual? That's basically what you're doing in the Gaussian case.

Comment: @Dan, in case of gaussian residual score of '0' means the observed and the predicted values are similar (or same). In case of gamma, what residual score represents the good agreement between observed and predicted response value? Basically what is the calculation behind it? Is it right to assume high residual score to be proxy for high unexplained variance in case of gamma as well?

Comment: In an ordinary linear regression, the model is $y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \cdots + \epsilon$.  The unexplained variance is the variance of the error term $\epsilon$.  The generalized linear regression involves two modifications:  a link function (which you can think of as a transformation of $y$) and a non-Gaussian distribution for the error term $\epsilon$.  The unexplained variance is still the variance of $\epsilon$.  Though — as with the covariates — the proper interpretation of the values of the errors also depends on the link function.

Comment: @Dan, The link function in my case is "inverse" (family=Gamma, link=inverse). Does "high residual score -  proxy for high unexplained variance" hold true in this case as well?